# Ionic Framework Code Injection

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I started using the Ionic cross-platform framework today. I created a simple iOS application and it runs perfectly fine using the conventional iOS emulator locally on my mac. Is there a way I can edit the code and inject it while the app is running on the simulator through Ionic?

Comment: Look for `livereload` in http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html